# How can I catch an exception and continue despite an error

Tags: php

I'd like to able to catch an exception and continue with the execution of other subsequent functions (and possibly log an error in the catch section). In the code sample below, there are instances where $html->find doesn't find the element and returns error exception undefined offset. In such cases, the entire script fails. I don't want to specifically test for this error but rather any error that may occur within the code block in the try section.

```
public function parsePage1($provider)
{
  $path = $this->getFile($provider);
  $link = $this->links[$provider];
  if (file_exists($path)) {
    $string = file_get_contents($path);
    $html = \HTMLDomParser::str_get_html($string);
    $wrapper = $html->find('.classToLookFor')[0];

    unset($string);
  }

}

try {
  $this->parsePage1('nameOfProvider');
} catch(Exception $e) {
  // continue...
}

try {
  $this->parsePage2('nameOfProvider');
} catch(Exception $e) {
  // continue...
}
```

Comment: That is what try-catch blocks do.  What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to make the code within the `try` block continue past an exception. An exception terminates the function just like a `return` would; there is no way to restore the state of the function afterwards.

Instead, avoid triggering the error in the first place:

```
$wrappers = $html->find('.classToLookFor'); # <-- no [0]!
if (count($wrappers)) {
    $wrapper = $wrappers[0];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Got it. I'll approach it this way then.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, the 'error' in this case was a notice.  If your errorlevel does not include notices, which is typically the case in production, your code will continue past that point.

With that said, Notices and warnings are intended for developers to add checks for expected input, as in duskwuff's example.

Unfortunatley, duskwuff's answer is problematic with the most recent versions of php at 7.2+.  This is because count() [expects either an array or an object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) that implements `countable`.

With the newest version you will get a Warning:

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in
```

You will be back where you were before using count() only.  A simple fix for that is to add a check for is_array.

```
$wrappers = $html->find('.classToLookFor'); # <-- no [0]!
if (is_array($wrappers) && count($wrappers)) {
    $wrapper = $wrappers[0];
    ...
}
```

I also want to point out, that per my original comment, the whole purpose of exception catching is to protect against program termination errors.

This was not a good example of the types of errors where you should apply try-catch, but to be clear, your original code does continue... just not within the try section of the code, but after the catch()

This simulation of your original problem illustrates that:

```
<?php

function findit($foo) {
    return $foo[0];
}

try {
    findit('');   
} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);   
}

echo 'Hey look we continued';
```

Output will be something like:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0 in ... on line 4
Hey look we continued
```

I feel this needs to be added as a response because people in the future are going to probably find this question, which really has nothing much to do with try-catch handling, and really has to do with code that expects to work with an array, but might not get one.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Makes sense now. Already did it by avoiding errors in the first place but try catches will come in handy when doing refactoring. Much appreciated.